# How to quickly check large number of URLs if they're still valid (or 404/otherwise missing)

Tags: url

Urls are already conveniently in a text file, one line per url, so it's probably trivial curl/wget/LWP one-liner. Anybody cares to share such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With LWP you can do this (redirecting output to a file if you so wished)

```
linux-t77m$ cat urls
http://google.com
http://stackoverflow.com
http://yahoo.com
linux-t77m$ cat urls | while read i ;do echo -n $i" "; lwp-request $i -sd; done
http://google.com 200 OK
http://stackoverflow.com 200 OK
http://yahoo.com 200 OK
```

The quickest way (as in getting the results faster) would be to launch processes in parallel, of course.